# How to avoid duplication of messages that are being pushed into a Kafka topic using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have the following producer code:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var KafkaProducer = kafka.Producer;
var KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage; 
var jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(request.object);

//I have to define client every time this endpoint is hit.
var client = new kafka.Client();
var producerKafka = new KafkaProducer(client);
var km = new KeyedMessage('key', 'message');
payloads = [
    { topic: 'collect-response', messages: jsonRequest, partition: 0 }
];
producerKafka.on('ready', function () {
    producerKafka.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
producerKafka.on('error', function (err) {})
```

Now, my task is to avoid de duplication of messages being written here.

Answer (score 0):

[This section](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?) of Kafka FAQ should be useful:

> **How do I get exactly-once messaging from Kafka?**
>
> Exactly once semantics has two parts: avoiding duplication during data
>   production
>   and avoiding duplicates during data consumption.
>
> There are two approaches to getting exactly once semantics during data
>   production:
>
> Use a single-writer per partition and every time you get a network
>   error check the last message in that partition to see if your last
>   write succeeded Include a primary key (UUID or something) in the
>   message and deduplicate on the consumer.
>
> If you do one of these things, the log that Kafka hosts will be
>   duplicate-free. However, reading without duplicates depends on some
>   co-operation from the consumer too. If the consumer is periodically
>   checkpointing its position then if it fails and restarts it will
>   restart from the checkpointed position. Thus if the data output and
>   the checkpoint are not written atomically it will be possible to get
>   duplicates here as well. This problem is particular to your storage
>   system. For example, if you are using a database you could commit
>   these together in a transaction. The HDFS loader Camus that LinkedIn
>   wrote does something like this for Hadoop loads. The other alternative
>   that doesn't require a transaction is to store the offset with the
>   data loaded and deduplicate using the topic/partition/offset
>   combination.
>
> I think there are two improvements that would make this a lot easier:
>
> Producer idempotence could be done automatically and much more cheaply
>   by optionally integrating support for this on the server. The existing
>   high-level consumer doesn't expose a lot of the more fine grained
>   control of offsets (e.g. to reset your position). We will be working
>   on that soon

Comment: I read this, than you very much. However, could you please help me at the code level?

Comment: You need to first find out why exactly you are producing duplicate messages. And within what time window you need to de-duplicate. (and de-duplicating on the consumer -- or by an extra stream processor between the two -- may also be a good option if the producer cannot do it easily).